# Create a html file and save in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a asp.net project. I'm trying to send mail contains a html page in attachment. I m generating HTML code. Now I want to write my HTML page and save it in a folder. I checked in web and this site but didn't find the working codes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Send HTML in an email, or create a directory for use in ASP or just create a basic HTML page?

Comment: If you do want to make a basic HTML web page. Try http://www.w3schools.com and look under the HTML section to start.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`File.WriteAllText()`  should do the Job

```
string content = GenerateHtml();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yoursite.htm", content);
```

Comment: Actually, Perfectly like this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlTextWriter, something like this:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
...
        }
```